# Error al Mostrar datos en TableView

Tags: javafx

buen día a todos, hice la mejora del código , pero tengo un problema, me muestra todos los registros de la BD excepto el ultimo que agrego, pero cuando cierro el programa y le doy mostrar el registro aparece.

clase mostraregistros:

```
package application;

import javafx.collections.*;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class Mostraregistros  implements Initializable  {

     ObservableList <cliente> data =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML TableView<cliente>  tablacliente;
    @FXML TableColumn<cliente, String> nombrescol;
    @FXML TableColumn<cliente,String > apellidoscol;
    @FXML TableColumn<cliente, Integer>  clienteid;
    @FXML private Button mtn;





    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {


         Connection conn=null;{
         try {

             conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba", "sa", "milkas87");
             Statement mostrar=conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs;
             rs= mostrar.executeQuery("select * from cliente");


             while ( rs.next() ) 
             {
                data.add(new cliente(
                        rs.getString("nombre"),
                        rs.getString("apellido"),
                        rs.getInt("id")
                        ));

             }



             if(conn!=null)
                 System.out.println("conexion exitosa");


         } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
         mtn.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                    alert.setTitle("Informacion");
                    alert.setHeaderText(null);
                    alert.setContentText("Mostrando Todos los Registros");
           alert.showAndWait();
           nombrescol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory <cliente, String>("nombres"));
            apellidoscol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory <cliente, String>("apellidos"));
            clienteid.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory <cliente, Integer>("id_cliente"));
            tablacliente.setItems(data); 

                }
            }); 
    }

}
```

código FXMl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import application.cliente.*?>

<?import application.Mostraregistros.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="634.0" prefWidth="626.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.ConexionSQL">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="5.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="581.0" prefWidth="977.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="nm" layoutX="125.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="205.0" text="nombres" />
            <TextField fx:id="ap" layoutX="125.0" layoutY="133.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="205.0" text="apellidos" />
            <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="137.0" text="NOMBRES" />
            <Button fx:id="btn" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="216.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btn" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="84.0" text="AGREGAR" />
            <Label layoutX="27.0" layoutY="141.0" text="APELLIDOS" />
            <TableView fx:id="tablacliente" layoutX="346.0" layoutY="47.0" prefHeight="448.0" prefWidth="553.0">
              <columns> 
                  <TableColumn fx:id="clienteid" prefWidth="225.0" text="CLIENTE ID"/> 

                <TableColumn fx:id="nombrescol" prefWidth="206.0" text="NOMBRES"/>

                <TableColumn fx:id="apellidoscol" prefWidth="161.0" text="APELLIDOS"/>

              </columns>
            </TableView>
            <Button fx:id="mtn" layoutX="138.0" layoutY="216.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="144.0" text="MOSTRAR REGISTROS" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

la clase cliente

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class cliente{


    private StringProperty nombres;
    private StringProperty apellidos;
    private IntegerProperty id_cliente;

public cliente ( String nombres, String apellidos, Integer id_cliente) {
    this.nombres=  new SimpleStringProperty (nombres);
    this.apellidos= new SimpleStringProperty ( apellidos);
    this.id_cliente=new SimpleIntegerProperty (id_cliente);
}


public String getNombres() {
    return nombres.get();
}

public  void  setNombres(String nombres) {
    this.nombres=new SimpleStringProperty (nombres);
}



public String getApellidos() {
    return apellidos.get();
}


public  void  setApellidos(String apellidos) {
    this.apellidos=new SimpleStringProperty ( apellidos);
}



public Integer getId_cliente() {
    return id_cliente.get();
}



public  void  setid_cliente(Integer id_cliente) {
    this.id_cliente=new SimpleIntegerProperty (id_cliente);
}




}
```

les agradeceria una mano de ayuda en esto. Gracias y feliz dia.

Comment: Deberías acotar un poco el ámbito. No sabemos si el problema es que no recuperas ningún registro de la BD, o si el problema está al mostrar los datos.

Comment: al insertar los registros en la bd todo va bien, pero al mostrarlos, el tableview no muestra ningun registro, en stackoverflow version ingles me dijeron que tenia un problema con las propiedades de clase cliente ; este es el topic  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619757/how-to-display-correctly-data-in-tableview?noredirect=1#comment92183664_52619757, de igual forma voy añadir la clase "conexionSQl"

Comment: @SJuan76 alguna idea con el codigo? me ayudaria mucho . gracias.

Comment: Haz caso del comentario de kleopatra. Mete los registros "a mano" o muestra por log los datos de los registros que cargas. Lo primero que necesitas es saber qué problema tienes (¿problemas con BD?¿de visualización?)

Comment: a mano? no entiendo?

Comment: @Sjuan76 arregle el codigo pero necesito tu ayuda, cuando doy clic al boton mostrar muestra todos los registros de la BD, pero cuando anexo uno nuevo y le doy clic en mostrar, no lo hace, tengo que cerrar el programa y darle clic en mostrar para que lo visualize. edite el codigo para que porfa me indique que hago mal?

Comment: @Sjuan76 necesito una ayuda departe tuya mi amigo.